# How to call Class in one module from an imported module in android

Tags: java, android, module

I have two modules in my project app and app-detection which I imported into my current project and it compiles perfectly.
The dependency is as follows:

```
implementation project(path: ':app-detection',configuration: 'default')
```

This was imported in my app module

However when I try to call a class from the app-detection module into my app module which I'm dependent on it doesn't recognize it or the import statement. How do I go about calling a class from the other module in my project? For example as shown below there is a DetectorActivity class in my app-detection module that I would like to call in my app module, but it doesn't recognize it.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.other:
        Intent intent=new Intent(BindGlassActivity.this,QRCodeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    case R.id.translationButton:
        Intent secondIntent = new Intent(BindGlassActivity.this,DetectorActivity.class);
        startActivity(secondIntent);
        finish();
        break;
    default: break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: did you add it in the settings.gradle like  include ':app-detection'?

Comment: @Greeshma yes I added it there also